# Problem verify smart contract by harhdat

Tags: web3js, hardhat

I recently used hardhat as a compiler for deploying SC and feel it really efficient. However, when I try to verify the SC using

npx hardhat verify --network bsc_testnet 0x....

I got the following error

Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: More than one contract was found to match the deployed bytecode.
Please use the contract parameter with one of the following contracts:

- @openzeppelin/contracts/MyTest.sol:MyTest
- contracts/MyTest.sol: MyTest

For example:

hardhat verify --contract contracts/Example.sol:ExampleContract

If you are running the verify subtask from within Hardhat instead:

await run("verify:verify", {
,
contract: "contracts/Example.sol:ExampleContract"
};

Please help me. Thank much everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you have multiple contract with the same name of MyTest. You can easily obtain it from the artifacts/ folder after

```
npx hardhat compile
```

In order to fix the error, you just need to pass the right contract instance as

```
npx hardhat verify ---contract "contracts/MyTest.sol:MyTest" --network bsc_testnet "your_contract_address" "argument_if_have"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs because of multiple presences of the same contract. As mentioned in the error message itself, try running this command instead.

```
npx hardhat verify --contract "contracts/MyTest.sol:MyTest" --network bsc_testnet 0x....
```

This command will tell hardhat the exact file to verify, which is I assume `MyTest.sol` inside the contract folder.